# Select and display Single Value from SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql

consider we have a database with lots of people's details.
I want to filter that result buy available data.
if the table structure is like following,

[image: database sample]

How to display only results from user with country "India".
It will be possible by accessing object attributes, but I want to add this feature to the following script. 
I am not an expert and this script seems to be so difficult for me to understand.

Pagination.php

```
<?php
namespace Phppot;

use Phppot\DataSource;

class Pagination
{

    private $ds;

    function __construct()
    {
        require_once __DIR__ . './../lib/DataSource.php';
        $this->ds = new DataSource();
    }

    public function getPage()
    {
        // adding limits to select query
        require_once __DIR__ . './../Common/Config.php';
        $limit = Config::LIMIT_PER_PAGE;

        // Look for a GET variable page if not found default is 1.
        if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
            $pn = $_GET["page"];
        } else {
            $pn = 1;
        }
        $startFrom = ($pn - 1) * $limit;

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_animal LIMIT ? , ?';
        $paramType = 'ii';
        $paramValue = array(
            $startFrom,
            $limit
        );
        $result = $this->ds->select($query, $paramType, $paramValue);
        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllRecords()
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_animal';
        $totalRecords = $this->ds->getRecordCount($query);
        return $totalRecords;
    }
}
?>
```

I just want to filter the result.
Full script link https://phppot.com/php/how-to-add-pagination-in-php-with-mysql/
If possible, please add an option to filter the result by an animal name (Common Name), for example "Lion".

Update, here is the working code

```
<?php
namespace Phppot;

use Phppot\DataSource;

class Pagination
{

    private $ds;

    function __construct()
    {
        require_once __DIR__ . './../lib/DataSource.php';
        $this->ds = new DataSource();
    }

    public function getPage()
    {
        // adding limits to select query
        require_once __DIR__ . './../Common/Config.php';
        $limit = Config::LIMIT_PER_PAGE;

        // Look for a GET variable page if not found default is 1.
        if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
            $pn = $_GET["page"];
        } else {
            $pn = 1;
        }
        $startFrom = ($pn - 1) * $limit;

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_animal WHERE common_name=Lion LIMIT ? , ?';
        $paramType = 'ii';
        $paramValue = array(
            $startFrom,
            $limit
        );
        $result = $this->ds->select($query, $paramType, $paramValue);
        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllRecords()
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_animal WHERE common_name=Lion';
        $totalRecords = $this->ds->getRecordCount($query);
        return $totalRecords;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is fairly basic SQL - you just need to alter your query to include a WHERE clause to specify the condition(s) that you want. After you have that, you'll probably want to add some way for the user to specify the search string, rather than having it hard-coded.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it works now. I have added updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution

```
<?php
namespace Phppot;

use Phppot\DataSource;

class Pagination
{

    private $ds;

    function __construct()
    {
        require_once __DIR__ . './../lib/DataSource.php';
        $this->ds = new DataSource();
    }

    public function getPage()
    {
        // adding limits to select query
        require_once __DIR__ . './../Common/Config.php';
        $limit = Config::LIMIT_PER_PAGE;

        // Look for a GET variable page if not found default is 1.
        if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
            $pn = $_GET["page"];
        } else {
            $pn = 1;
        }
        $startFrom = ($pn - 1) * $limit;

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_animal WHERE common_name=Lion LIMIT ? , ?';
        $paramType = 'ii';
        $paramValue = array(
            $startFrom,
            $limit
        );
        $result = $this->ds->select($query, $paramType, $paramValue);
        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllRecords()
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_animal WHERE common_name=Lion';
        $totalRecords = $this->ds->getRecordCount($query);
        return $totalRecords;
    }
}
?>
```